# A Puzzle That Beats The OP

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> With a voice on my first, the OP doesn't have me; he lives in a foreign country.
>
> With a raise on my second, the OP simply cannot do me; I am so wild.
>
> With a block on my fourth, the OP has simply done me; so will the answerer.
>
> With a retraction on my fourth, the OP maybe will do me; he wants to be a topologist.

What am I?

**Subtle Hint:**

> It's a 4-letter word.

Comment: Is there a typo here? You mention block on fourth and retraction on fourth, but no mention of your third.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> It's *time* /tɑjm/.

> With a voice on my first, the OP doesn't have me; he lives in a foreign country.

> Voice the /t/ to /d/ to get *dime*, a coin in the USA. The OP's profile indicates he lives outside the USA.

> With a raise on my second, the OP simply cannot do me; I am so wild.

> Raise /ɑ/ to /e/ to get *tame*.

> With a block on my fourth, the OP has simply done me; so will the answerer.

> Make the /m/ a stop to get *type*.

> With a retraction on my fourth, the OP maybe will do me; he wants to be a topologist.

> Retract the /m/ to an /ŋ/ to get *tying*. (Knot theory is a branch of topology.)